# Godaddy multiple domain problem

Tags: web-hosting, godaddy

I have godaddy deluxe plan and here is my problem:

I have two domains for example: e1.com and e2.com. Both are hosted in same hosting plan. First I created a folder for each domain in the root folder and uploaded two web site but when I'm trying to run my sites, the URL for e1 always shows `http://e1.com/e1/` and for e2 it shows `http://e2.com/e2`. Can I avoid showing e1 and e2 folder and only show `http://e1.com` and `http://e2.com`?

Thank you.

Comment: i think this is more suited to http://webmasters.stackexchange.com

Comment: thanks Darko Z next time i'll post on that for now please let me get an answer :)

Comment: Usually I just get on the phone with GoDaddy support and have them walk me through the fix.  Dealing with their interface is just too painful :)

Answer (score 3):

Last time I dealt with GoDaddy, I had multiple domains.

The hosting plan will automatically be under e1.com when you go to the 
1) /www/ folder or /public_html/ folder create one that says e2.
2) Then simply fill out a simple index.html file and just go to "www.e2.com" 
3) Then you also have to go into the domain manager and create new folder named e2 (what i named my folder through ftp) and you should then be good to go.  Hope it works for you.